# php cookies issue

Tags: php, cookies

I have code,
echo shows nothing?? Why

```
<?php
$szukane = $_POST['szukane'];
$tablica = Array('a' => 'az', 'b' => 'sx');
setcookie('tablica', serialize($tablica));
$un_tablica = unserialize($_COOKIE['tablica']);
echo $un_tablica['a'];
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Common Pitfalls:
>
> - Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.

Answer (score -1):

I have to change this:

```
$un_tablica = unserialize($_COOKIE['tablica']);
```

for this:

```
$un_tablica = unserialize(StripSlashes($_COOKIE['tablica']);
```